# Django: Issue with JSON and Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, python, django, json, internet-explorer-9

have a problem with JSON not working with Internet Explorer (IE9).
I've searched the web alot, and tried the different solutions, but nothing seems to work for me. So thought it was time to create a SO account and ask my first question.

I'm using JSON and jQuery/AJAX to create a simple upload progress indicator
The indicator works fine in Firefox and Chrome

This is my view function:

```
@never_cache
@admin_required
@render_to("editor/edit_file.html")
def edit_file(request, file_id=None):
    if file_id:
        try:
            file = Document.objects.get(pk=file_id)
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, instance=file)
        except Document.DoesNotExist:
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None)
    else:
        dir_id = request.GET.get("dir")
        if dir_id:
            try:
                dir = Directory.objects.get(pk=dir_id)
                form = DocumentForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, initial ={"directory":dir_id, "available_to":dir.available_to})
            except:
                form = DocumentForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None)
        else:
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None)

    result = {}
    response = locals()

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            file = form.save()
            result["status"] = "ok"
            result["href"] = reverse("portal.editor.views.files_list", args=[file.directory.pk])
            if not request.is_ajax():
                response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("portal.editor.views.files_list", args=[file.directory.pk]))
        else:
            result[status] = "error"
        if request.is_ajax():
            response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype="text/plain")
            add_never_cache_headers(response)
    return response
```

and here is my jQuery code:

```
if ($("#id_edit_form").length > 0) {
    $("#id_edit_form").ajaxForm({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSubmit:  function (formData, jqForm, options) {
            $("#id_overlay").height($(document).height()).show();
        },
        success: function (response, status, xhr, $form) {
            $("#id_overlay").hide();
            if (status === "success") {
                if (response.status === "ok") {
                    location.href = response.href;
                } else if (response.status === "error") {
                    for (var item in response.form) {
                        $("#id_" + item).parent("p").next("p.js_form-error").html(response.form[item][0]);
                    }
                } else { alert(response.result); }
            } else { alert("Error status:", status); }
        }
    });
}
```

I feel like I've tried everything. Also tried changing mimetype to "text/plain" and it still didn't work.
I'm using Django 1.3, Python 2.6 and jQuery 1.6.1 with nginx server.

What about mimetype in nginx/mime.types? Should I add json in this file?
I really need help with this, since I've been tearing my head of due to this problem!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you observe (error messages in console etc.). Also, the Python code you posted is syntactically invalid and cannot work as is.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: it wasn't the issue itself I fixed, but the syntax error Vasily mentioned

Comment: You still haven’t described your problem. You say “it still didn't work”, but what does that mean? There are many ways your code can possibly “not work”.

Comment: I can't seem to find the issue in Fiddler (maybe I just don't know where to look).

When a user uploads a file, an overlay is displayed until the upload is finished. This works smoothly in Firefox.

In IE however, the overlay "hangs" in the browser, meaning it doesn't receive the JSON from the django view. Model is created, and file is uploaded, but you have to refresh page to be able to browse again.

I have asked a developer to look into the error in Fiddler. Maybe he can find the issue.

Comment: @rulzart IE has developer tools where you can look at the requests and responses. You don’t need Fiddler for that. You can also add more debug alerts to your `success` callback to see what’s going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the syntax error was probably that comma after last }

```
success:       function(response, status, xhr, $form){
            $("#id_overlay").hide();
                if( status == "success" ){
                    if( response.status == "ok"){
                        location.href = response.href;
                    }else
                    if(response.status == "error" ){
                        for(var item in response.form){
                            $("#id_"+item).parent("p").next("p.js_form-error").html(response.form[item][0]);
                        }
                    }else
                        alert(response.result);
                }else
                    alert("Error status:", status);
        },
```

THAT last comma. IE is very picky about such stuff.

I did some reading about ajaxForm that you are using. Is this that : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ ? Seems to me that you could use it much easyer or forget about it completely and use jquery ajax like this:

```
$('a.submit').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var f = $(this).parents('form');
    data = f.serialize();
    if (contactIsWorking == false){
        $.ajax({
            'type':'POST',
            'url': '/contactform/',
            'data': data,
            'datatype':'json',
            'beforeSend':function(){
                contactIsWorking = true;
            },
            'success':function(data, textStatus){
                postHandler(f, data);
            },
            'error':function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            },
            'timeout':function(data){
            },
            'complete':function(data){
                contactIsWorking = false;
                spinner.fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Took this code quickly from one of my projects - it probably has too much info but i guess you can filter out whats needed

Comment: FYI, I still haven't found a solution to this problem.
I also went through my JS code with JSLint, to fix anything that might interfere with IE, and still no luck.
IE is hell to code for!

Comment: did you remove that comma after success callbacks } ?. IE is very picky about such things.

Comment: Yes I did. I edited my post with the new view and JS.

I've tried different content-types (text/plain, application/json, etc). Which is the correct one to use?

And should I have a "type" in the js code? Like "typ": GET or "type": POST ?

Comment: no need to fiddle with content types. keep dataType json, but yes you should have type there also since default type is GET not POST for jquery ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If that comma was not a problem then what kind of error does Ie raise? It usually gives at least SOME information about whats wrong

Comment: It doesn't give me any error (not any pop-up with JavaScript error as it usually does).
Can't seem to find the error in the debug tool either - or maybe I just don't know what to look for.

Will try with type: POST later on, when I get home

Comment: IE errors does not always result in popups -they can be just that exclamation mark on yellow background in bottom left corner. If you click on it then you might see the real message.

Comment: Hey Zaya. I used Fiddler2 to debug, and it looks like IE9 doesn't get the content-type from django at all. It's set to "text/plain; charset=utf-8", but in Fiddler2 it shows up as text/html. Have any idea why it does that? It shows the correct content-type in FF.

Comment: in that case - how are you retuning it in django? Im using return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response, cls = LazyEncoder), content_type='application/json') in most of cases where i have to return json. Dont mind the LazyEncoder.

Comment: At the moment it's like this: HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result, mimetype="text/plain"))
The reason I use mimetype is because I'm using django 1.3 (content-type came later, right?)

Comment: yes but content_type or mimetype is HttpResponse kwarg not simplejson.dumps kwarg. Should be HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result), mimetype="text/plain") and if you want to return json and want browsers/jquery understand its json, then the type should be application/json not text/plain. As far as i know anyway.

Comment: My mistake, my code is indeed simplejson.dumps(result), mimetype="text/plain". Didn't have my code infront of me when posting it here.

Comment: well.. if we ever want to solve this issue, you should probably update your first post with all the relevant code and whatnot and see what errors IE shows - because it surely shows some errors.

Comment: Will do so when I get home from work. But it doesn't show me any error, that's the weird part. Or maybe I just can't see that it's throwing an error.

Comment: I have updated my code - this time with the whole view function. About the mimetype/contenttype, I've read several places that IE does NOT like application/javascript or json, and therefor text/plain is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this bug went away when I upgraded to Django 1.5.

Seems like django 1.3 had some issues with mimetypes/content-types and JSON (now I also use built-in json instead of simplejson)